# Basic kafka topic availability checker

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I need a simple health checker for `Apache Kafka`. I dont want something large and complex like `Yahoo Kafka Manager`, basically I want to check if a topic is healthy or not and if a consumer is healthy.

My first idea was to create a separate `heart-beat` topic and periodically send and read messages to/from it in order to check availability and latency.

The second idea is to read all the data from `Apache Zookeeper`. I can get all brokers, partitions, topics etc. from ZK, but I dont know if ZK can provide something like failure detection info.

As I said, I need something simple that I can use in my app health checker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some existing **tools** you can try them out if you haven't yet -

**[Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow)** Linkedin's Kafka Consumer Lag Checking

**[exhibitor](https://github.com/Netflix/exhibitor)** Netflix's ZooKeeper co-process for instance monitoring, backup/recovery, cleanup and visualization.

[**Kafka System Tools**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools) Kafka command line tools

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nresare/kafka-availability-tester sounds like it might be a good solution providing synthetic load to confirm that messages can be produced and consumed.